# Different behaviour in different scenarios of "warning C4800: 'int' : forcing value to bool 'true' or 'false'"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am not able to understand the following behavior of the this warning.

```
case 1:
bool read = (33 & 3) ; //No Warning issued by vs 2013

case 2:
int b = 33;
bool read = (b & 3) ; //Now compiler is generating C4800 warning.
```

Why compiler is generating warning in case 2 while it is not issuing any warning in case 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first case you create boolean variable from expression. It is possible

```
std::cout << std::is_constructible<decltype((33 & 3)), bool>::value<<std::endl; // output: 1
```

In second case you construct int variable from expression. Type of this expression `int`

```
std::cout << typeid(b & 3).name() << std::endl; // output: i
```

And, finally, you use implicit type conversion from int to bool and get warning.

Answer (score 3):

C4800 is a *performance* warning - coercing an integer to `bool` at runtime has a cost.
It has nothing to do with logical correctness.

The most common occurrence of the coersion (and the warning) is when you interface with code that uses integers (`BOOL` in VC++) for booleans.

The compile-time coercion in your first snippet incurs no runtime overhead, so there is no warning.

To get rid of the warning, get rid of the coercion:

```
bool read = (b & 3) != 0;
```

Comment: I'd still say the compiler warning is nonsense, because the code you suggest as alternative is probably equivalent to the code it generates itself, but that doesn't cause a warning. Actually, I seem to remember that this very old warning is only left in place and using this very text for some legacy reasons, and that even the folks at MS would otherwise ignore/disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning the two cases you mention, their difference is that in one case the whole integral value is a compile-time constant (or at least it can easily be reduced to one). Maybe the assumption is that initialization with constant expressions should not trigger this warning? I'd check the bug tracking system of the vendor for further info.

However, in practice I'd ignore or even disable this warning. Consider the case of testing for a single bit: `bool negative = byte & 0x80;`. This code is what I'd call idiomatic code and it generates a warning. To me, that's a proof why this warning is bad.

Comment: Well `byte & 0x80` does not return a bool. To actually avoid the warning instead of ignoring it use `byte & 0x80 != 0` which makes the conversion explicit.

Comment: I'm fully aware of this, @Matthäus. The point is that this is the usual way to test for a bit and if the compiler annoys me with warnings about that, it is actually not being helpful. Similarly, I don't compare pointers to null in order to see if they are null, I just use them in a place where a boolean expression is expected and use the implicit conversion.

Comment: `bool valid = ptr;` where `ptr` is some pointer will trigger the same warning in VC, on the other hand `if (i)` for some `int i` will not. So VC advocates explicit conversions where an expression is not contextually convertible. Actually this is consistent to `explicit operator bool`.